# Fourier and differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Hey right now I'm practising Fourierseries and found this problem, just so you know it's my first time using Fourier to solve differential equations.
$$ f''(x) + f(x) = 3\cos(2x) $$

Comment: Please consider using \cos instead of writing cos. Also in higher math, we tend to not explicitly write the multiplication sign. You can use \cdot when you multiply numerical values like $0.234\cdot 0.123$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
F[f''(x)+f(x)]=F[3\cos(2x)]
$$

or

$$
((i \omega)^2+1)F(\omega) = 3 \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (w-2)+3 \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (w+2)
$$

and then

$$
F(\omega) = \frac{3 \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (w-2)+3 \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (w+2)}{((i \omega)^2+1)}
$$

and finally

$$
F^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (w-2)+3 \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (w+2)}{((i \omega)^2+1)}\right) = -\cos(2 x)
$$

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'm just stupid but how we get $$ \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$ do I miss something obvious ?

Comment: Check the definition for the pair $F, F^{-1}$. Both should be consistent.